# Seaborn Barplot and Lineplot(shared Y-Axis) not working with the same working code of other graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, seaborn

With the help of this site, I have been able to plot multiple graph types, but there is one graph that just wont work, even when I utilize the same exact code that works on another graph.

This working code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,6))
g = sns.lineplot(x='report_date',  y='UTL_R', data=tm_daily_df, ax=ax, hue = 'shift',
             marker='o', markersize=10)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
g = sns.barplot(x='report_date',  y='Head_Count', data=tm_daily_df, ax=ax2, hue='shift',alpha=.5)
ax.set_title('--Utilization Ratio-- vs □□HeadCount□□', fontsize = 17)
plt.show()
```

Where tm_daily_df is this data

```
  report_date shift  UTL_R  Head_Count
0      3/31/19     A   1.00          30
1       4/1/19     A   1.05          58
2       4/2/19     A   1.02          64
3       4/3/19     A   1.00          61
4       4/4/19     A   1.00          55
5       4/5/19     A   0.97          53
6       4/6/19     A   1.02          40
7      3/31/19     1   0.97          10
8      3/31/19     2   1.07           3
9      3/31/19     3   1.01           7
10      4/1/19     1   1.10          24
11      4/1/19     2   1.02          14
12      4/1/19     3   1.00          10
13      4/2/19     1   1.04          26
14      4/2/19     2   1.02          18
15      4/2/19     3   0.98          10
16      4/3/19     1   0.95          25
17      4/3/19     2   0.99          16
18      4/3/19     3   1.10          10
19      4/4/19     1   1.05          17
20      4/4/19     2   0.95          15
21      4/4/19     3   1.00          13
22      4/5/19     1   0.94          20
23      4/5/19     2   1.02          15
24      4/5/19     3   0.95           8
25      4/6/19     1   1.07          19
26      4/6/19     2   1.06           9
27      4/6/19     3   0.81           2
```

Provides this result:

[image: Graph]

Now, when I try to do the exact same for a similar set of data
job_hours_df_shiftday_grouped =

```
   report_date  shift  999  load_count
0   2019-03-31      1   42       227.0
1   2019-03-31      2   13       141.0
2   2019-03-31      3   79       267.0
3   2019-04-01      1  146       580.0
4   2019-04-01      2  177       627.0
5   2019-04-01      3  127       460.0
6   2019-04-02      1  192       583.0
7   2019-04-02      2  121       626.0
8   2019-04-02      3   98       291.0
9   2019-04-03      1  172       580.0
10  2019-04-03      2   83       372.0
11  2019-04-03      3   78       323.0
12  2019-04-04      1   83       403.0
13  2019-04-04      2   69       340.0
14  2019-04-04      3   86       268.0
15  2019-04-05      1  164       567.0
16  2019-04-05      2  169       593.0
17  2019-04-05      3   48       249.0
18  2019-04-06      1  102       304.0
19  2019-04-06      2   48       246.0
20  2019-04-06      3    4         0.0
```

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,6))
g = sns.lineplot(x='report_date',  y='999', data=job_hours_df_shiftday_grouped, ax=ax, hue = 'shift',
             marker='o', markersize=10)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
g = sns.barplot(x='report_date',y='load_count',data=job_hours_df_shiftday_grouped, ax=ax2, alpha=.5, 
                hue = 'shift')
ax.set_title('Daily 999 instances by Shift', fontsize = 20)
plt.show()
```

it returns this:
[image: Bad Graph]

Notice the dates and lack of lineplot but the secondary axis is there.
I have reformatted the dates, eliminated nulls, and even then, for some reason it does not even show the lineplot and the dates come out in the wrong format. What is happening??

Again, here is the working graph code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,6))
g = sns.lineplot(x='report_date',  y='UTL_R', 
data=tm_daily_df, ax=ax, hue = 'shift',
             marker='o', markersize=10)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
g = sns.barplot(x='report_date',  y='Head_Count', data=tm_daily_df, ax=ax2, hue='shift',alpha=.5)
ax.set_title('--Utilization Ratio-- vs □□HeadCount□□', fontsize = 17)
plt.show()
```

And here is the current bane of my existence:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,6))
g = sns.lineplot(x='report_date',  y='999', data=job_hours_df_shiftday_grouped, ax=ax, hue = 'shift',
             marker='o', markersize=10)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
g = sns.barplot(x='report_date',y='load_count', data=job_hours_df_shiftday_grouped, ax=ax2, alpha=.5, 
                hue = 'shift')
ax.set_title('Daily 999 instances by Shift', fontsize = 17)
plt.show()
```

I have no idea why the second graph code does not work. It comes from the same data source and uses the same working code.

Comment: There is a clear difference between the two datasets!

Comment: Values are different but datatypes are the same. What can possibly be ruining the graphs. If I do them seperately, line graph works like a charm, but once bar graph is added, the report dates get all iffy and such

Comment: You can find out about datatypes of the columns via `print(df.info())`

Comment: the data types are the same except when i turn it into the index it turns to a datetimeindex, but before it's an index, they are both objects. The error doesn't make sense

Comment: At least what gets plotted are strings in the first ("working") case, and datetime objects in the second ("non-working") case. If you say pandas shows the same datatype (object == string), then the conversion might happen inside of the seaborn function  for some unknown reason.